# Simple RSpec tests failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, rspec2

I'm following [this tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out) here, and everything has worked out very well so far.

But now that I've progressed to sessions, some simple rspec tests are failing:

```
describe SessionsController do

  #[...]

  describe "GET 'new'" do

    it "should have the right title" do
      get :new
      response.should have_selector( "title", :content => "Sign in" )
    end

  end

  #[...]

  describe "POST 'create'" do

    #[...]

    it "should have the right title" do
      post :create, :session => @attr
      response.should have_selector("title", :content => "Sign in")
    end

    #[...]
  end

end
```

When I run rspec, I always get:

> 1) SessionsController GET 'new' should
>   have the right title
>        Failure/Error: response.should have_selector( "title", :content =>
>   "Sign in
>   ) 
>          expected following output to contain a Sign in tag: 
>          
>   w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> 
>        # ./spec/controllers/sessions_controller_spec.rb:14:in
>   `block (3 levels) in '

When I access the sessions/new page, the page contains a title tag like the following:

```
<title>Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App | Sign in</title>
```

Why do those tests fail, while all other similar (= tests for the title tag) tests work fine?

Here's the SessionController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @title = 'Sign in'
  end

  def create

    user = User.authenticate( params[:session][:email], params[:session][:password] )

    if user.nil?
        flash.now[:error] = "Invalid email/password combination."
        @title = 'Sign in'
        render 'new'
    else
        sign_in user
        redirect_to user
    end
  end


    def destroy
        sign_out
        redirect_to root_path       
    end

end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

thx for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `render_views` to the top of the class. Without it, the actual html will not be generated and your `have_selector` tests will fail.